# Failed to pull image : rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: denied: access forbidden

Tags: docker, kubectl, docker-registry, kubernetes-deployment

I'm doing deployment into my kubernetes cluster. I have created secret for my private registry and deployment yaml file. I have applied them with `kubectl apply -f deployment.yml` with `"imagePullPolicy: always"` to deploy automatically some applications into my cluster without any problem. Now I'm using the same secret file to deploy another application and I'm facing this error:

> "Failed to pull image
> "lab.smartds.io:5060/market-place/marketplace-api:latest": rpc error:
> code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get
> https://lab.smartds.io:5060/v2/market-place/marketplace-api/manifests/latest:
> denied: access forbidden"

But I'm able to pull the same image manually using `docker pull imagename`. I don't know why.

Comment: See the Kubernetes documentation for help using [private registries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/). This describes one way to authenticate to a private registry. You will create a Kubernetes Secret that encapsulates the registry's credentials and then reference this Secret using `imagePullSecrets` in the Deployment.

Comment: @DazWilkin i have already use imagePullSecrets refering kubernetes documentation. i have used ithat secret to  deploy another applications in the same namespace as the one that i get the error during kubectl apply. and those applications are working very fine

Comment: i used **kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email> -n my-namespace** to create my secret with gitlab-personal token and in my deployment file i added **imagePullSecrets**

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Hopefully someone else can help.